# Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff {:code=>400, :url=>"https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_bulk"}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-elasticsearch

Logstash Config file

```
input {
 elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["https://staing-example.com:443"]
 user => "userName"
 password => "password"
 index => "testingindex"
 size => 100
 scroll => "1m"
 }
}

filter {

}


output {
 amazon_es {
 hosts => ["https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"]
 region => "us-east-1"
 aws_access_key_id => "access_key_id"
 aws_secret_access_key => "access_key_id"
 index => "testingindex"
}
}
```

Using Logstash to transferred from one elastic search server to amazon elastic search

For the above config, Logstash is continuously throwing

2019-10-10T16:00:51,232][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_bulk"}
[2019-10-10T16:00:52,127][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_bulk"}
[2019-10-10T16:00:52,317][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_bulk"}

Don't know the reason why it is happening

Comment: run logstash with --debug flag and post results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below solution solves the issue for me 
Click on the configured cluster in Amazon Elastic Search  [configure cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rCUs.png)

Now click on Advanced Option Where you can able to see the 
Allow APIs that can span multiple indices and bypass index-specific access policies - check in the policy 
[Advance Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mjDC.png)

Comment: This didn't work for me as the cluster was configured like so from the get go...here are other things to consider with the original elasticsearch plugin:   https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-elasticsearch-encountered-a-retryable-error-will-retry-with-exponential-backoff-code-400/138267/501717